# If, else-if loops in matlab

Tags: logic, matlab, programming

I'm having a bit of confusion with matlab.  I'm trying to generate a random number between zero and one, and then map that number to the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  Here's the code I have:

```
x=rand(1)

if( x < 3.2e-4)

    k = 0

elseif( 3.2001e-4 < x < 6.72e-3)

    k = 1
elseif(6.72001e-3 < x < 0.05792)

    k = 2

elseif(0.05792001 < x < 0.2627)

    k = 3

elseif(0.2627001 < x < 0.6723)

    k=4

else

    k = 5

end
```

Whenever I run the code, it only works part of the time.  For example, when I got x=0.5469, it says that k=5 when in reality k should take on the value of 4.

Any help/links are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that MATLAB supports double inequalities in this format. Try to write the if statements in this format:

`if ( 0.2627001 < x & x < 0.6723)`

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "if a < x < b" does not do what you think it does. Use "if a < x && x < b" instead. Extra credit: figure out how a < x < b actually evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a value falls within a range, you can use two separate comparison tests, joined with an AND condition, e.g.,

```
elseif ((3.2001e-4 < x) && (x < 6.72e-3))
```

There is another issue with the code above.  if `x` is `3.20009e-4`, you get `k` = `5`, which is not what you want.  What you should test for is:

```
elseif ((3.2e-4 <= x)  && (x < 6.72e-3))
```

However, you can simplify the code above further.  If the first test `(x < 3.2e-4)` is false, then `(3.2e-4 <= x)` is true, and the execution would go to the next else statement anyway, so you can just check for:

```
elseif (x < 6.72e-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify this as:

```
if( x < 3.2e-4)
  k = 0
elseif (x < 6.72e-3)
  k = 1
elseif (x < 0.05792)
  k = 2
elseif (x < 0.2627)
  k = 3
elseif (x < 0.6723)
  k = 4
else
  k = 5
end
```